# Windows vs Linux VM L3 Cache Size Discrepancy

Tags: performance, caching, architecture, virtual-machine, cpu-architecture

I have a query regarding the disparity in L3 cache size between native Windows and a Linux virtual machine (VM) running on it.

According to my CPU architecture documentation, the L3 cache size is specified as 24 MiB shared. However, when I run the lscpu command on the Linux VM, it reports 192 MiB. On the other hand, the Windows Task Manager displays 24 MiB, consistent with the official documentation.

Do you believe this difference could be due to the VM representing the L3 cache as 24 MiB for each core, resulting in a total of 24 MiB multiplied by 8 cores, hence 192 MiB for the L3 cache?

[https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tiger_Lake#:~:text=Tiger%20Lake%20is%20Intel%27s%20codename,%2210%20nm%20SuperFin%22](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tiger_Lake#:%7E:text=Tiger%20Lake%20is%20Intel%27s%20codename,%2210%20nm%20SuperFin%22)).

```
λ lscpu | grep -E '^Model|^Thread|^Core|^Socket|^CPU|^NUMA|cache:'
CPU op-mode(s):                     32-bit, 64-bit
CPU(s):                             8
Thread(s) per core:                 1
Core(s) per socket:                 8
Socket(s):                          1
NUMA node(s):                       1
CPU family:                         6
Model:                              141
Model name:                         11th Gen Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-11800H @ 2.30GHz
CPU MHz:                            2303.998
L1d cache:                          384 KiB
L1i cache:                          256 KiB
L2 cache:                           10 MiB
L3 cache:                           192 MiB
NUMA node0 CPU(s):                  0-7
```

Comment: 192 MB is clearly wrong. Your explanation is reasonable enough, but running Linux on bare hardware might give the same result, in which case you'd have to blame `lscpu` instead of the VM. But why does this matter?

Comment: Have you checked Intel's errata ("specification update") docs to see if it's mis-reported by CPUID?  If so, Windows might just know the right value based on model number and core count, and ignore wrong info from CPUID.  Hmm, 192 is `24 * 8`, so maybe `lscpu` is adding up the L3 cache size each core reports, even though it's actually shared.  It's already adding up the sizes of per-core private caches (which is a stupid marketing-style way to report sizes for per-core private caches, should be `48 KiB x 8` or `48 KiB per core`.)

Comment: Since this is in a VM, perhaps the VM is munging CPUID so the VM doesn't realize all 8 cores share the same L3, rather than each having their own.  Your VM is already choosing not to expose half the logical cores, only one logical core per physical core, so it's already playing some tricks with CPUID.

Comment: Thank you for your comments! The case I pointed is not important. However, the reason I have asked is to understand whether this is due to VM or lscpu or CPUID. Having reliable cpu profile information is important if you are doing cpu comparison and writing performance critical software.  I always use lscpu to quickly glance what I have and understand what to expect. When I noticed above phenomenon, I was surprised what is the reason...